# Online Booking Page

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to create a website for an imaginary hotel where every room has a name ("room of sun", "room of moon", etc.)

I'm making the booking page but how should I take the room's names from the database using this code:

```
echo'<select id="roomname" name="roomname" size="1"> ';
{
    include("include/connect.php"); 
    $conn=mysql_connect($HOST, $USER, $PASSWORD);
    $db_ok=mysql_select_db($DB, $conn);
    $cam=mysql_query("select Name from room", $conn);
    $ncam=mysql_num_rows($cam);
    for ($i=0;$i<$ncam;$i++) {          
        $f=mysql_result($cam,$i,"Name");
        echo "<option>$f</option>";
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
}
echo '</select>';
```

After have selected the room: the booking page has to show you the remaining part of the form with starting and ending dates (with the days when the room is free or rent) and how many people are taking that room.

Here comes the problem.. after I select the room, How can I manage in order that the webpage show you the other options and in particular the "select" that loads what's the maximum number of people that can take the room ? (kinda like the "select" I used to load the room's name ^^ )

Here there is an example:

```
echo'<select id="Npeople" name="Npeople" size="1"> ';
{
include("include/connect.php"); 
        $conn=mysql_connect($HOST, $USER, $PASSWORD);
        $db_ok=mysql_select_db($DB, $conn);
        $ris=mysql_query("select Nrmax from room where Name='<script type=text/javascript>document.booking.chamber.value</script>'", $conn);
        $ros=intval($ris);
        for ($o=0;$o<$ros;$o++) {    
        $u=mysql_result($ris,$o,"Nrmax"); 
    echo "<option>$u</option>";
        }
        mysql_close($conn);
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: You want to webpage show them after you have submitted the room or at the same page after user select's it from `select` list?

Comment: Eh, then I urge you to check course books, notes, etc. You need to create several pages, one to display the form where room is first selected, then show rest of data using javascript asynch calls (in this case I would recommend jQuery to be used, if you can decide). That JS must fetch from PHP script data so that it will "show the other options". This is your course work? Read jQuery, specially Ajax - get method (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Comment: You don't *need* to use ajax for this, nor several pages if you don't want to. Ajax may be more elegant but you should focus on getting the basics straight before going there. Several pages is a good way to divide logic and understand what's going on. However, from the `<script>` tag in the SQL query in your last code snippet, I'm unsure what your requirements are. Did you find that out yourself or did your professor instruct you to use that code? That may be an indication that you indeed are required to use some javascript/ajax

Comment: Guys, thanks for your help!.
Then I realised that a simple way to do it was to make the booking through 3 pages using $_SESSION's and so on!.
Last friday i succeed the exam with 28/30 (damn, he asked me 1 thing that wasn't in our study's documentation)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to Order the rooms during your Select Statements.

SELECT * FROM `<tbl_rooms>` WHERE `<conditions here>` ORDER BY `<room_size>` DESC, `<room_price>` ASC